# maven spring-security Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder.resolveJavaType(BasicValueBinder.java:1002)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'java.lang.reflect.Type org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager.toType(org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.XClass)'
```

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/kacpe/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.1.6.Final/hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/BasicValueBinder.class
```

The called method's class, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/kacpe/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager: file:/C:/Users/kacpe/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder and org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager

application.yaml

```
    spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurantoptimize
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database: mysql
    database-platform:  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.RestaurantOptimize</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestaurantOptimize-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestaurantOptimize-backend</name>
    <description>Backend of RestaurantOptimize</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

trued to run, spingBOOT application with JWT tokens and spring security on MAVEN

Comment: Remove the version from hibernate-core in your pom first...

Comment: didn't helped :(

Comment: Please add the full logging output which shows the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the version of the Spring Boot? I just had the same problem and solved it by changing Spring Boot version from 3.0.0 to 2.7.10. It's in parent tag, below artifactId tag.  Then replace all "jakarta" in files to "javax" and Project -> update maven project. (I'm using Eclipse)

I'm sorry that I can't provide any reference for now, as it just work for me. Hopefully this works for others too.